# Jupyter Save Hook not working after reinstalling python+pyenv

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, pyenv

I use a jupyter save hook to convert my notebooks into different formats which is defined in `/Users/corrie/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`. This was all working fine until I recently reinstalled my whole python environment (some environment stuff messed up).
I use `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenv` to manage my python environments, I had a slightly different setup before using `virtualenvwrapper` as well, so the reinstall is probably not 100% clean...

The save hook was still there after reinstalling but I had to reinstall jupyter again in my new python setup. It doesn't look like a clean reinstall, as many of my old kernels are still there (based on old environments that I thought should be gone..).
Anyway, jupyter lab works fine but it doesn't pick up on the save hook.

When I run `jupyter --config-dir` it outputs the correct folder `/Users/corrie/.jupyter` but it still doesn't recognize the save hook. I also tried explicitly setting `JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR` to the config folder but nothing changed.

I also tried copying the config file to `$PYENV_ROOT/versions/3.9.9/etc/jupyter/`
(3.9.9 is the version I get when running `pyenv which jupyter`), but also nothing.

How can I fix this? Also, ideally is there a way to not have to install jupyter again in every new environment?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue: the newest version of Jupyter Lab changed the name of the config file.
Renaming the config file from `jupyter_notebook_config.py` to either `jupyter_lab_config.py` or `jupyter_server_config.py` solved the issue.

See also this [issue](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12897).

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @Corrie's answer, but in my case updating `jupyter_notebook_config.py` to `jupyter_lab_config.py` has no effect

Updating `jupyter_server_config.py` fixed the issue.

```
IPython          : 8.4.0
ipykernel        : 6.15.1
ipywidgets       : 7.7.0
jupyter_client   : 7.3.4
jupyter_core     : 4.11.1
jupyter_server   : 1.18.1
jupyterlab       : 3.3.2
nbclient         : 0.6.7
nbconvert        : 7.0.0
nbformat         : 5.4.0
notebook         : 6.4.10
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.3.0
```